# Links within XPage Mobile Controls opening in same tab on iPad

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have to create a simple XPages application for iOS devices so want to use the XPages Mobile Controls which come with the Extension Library in 8.5.3 UP1.
On one of the pages, I need the users to be able to open links in new tabs, but I've found that even with the link target set to _blank, the links are opening in the same tab when opened on the iPad.  It works fine using Chrome on my laptop - opening in a new tab.   If I just create a simple XPage (not using the Single Page App control) with the same link control on it, the link opens ok in a separate tab on the iPad.

Is there any way to try and force the link into a new tab if I use the Mobile controls?

This is code from a simple test xpage - which results in the link opening in the same tab when I test it on an iPad:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" defaultLinkTarget="_blank">

    <xe:singlePageApp id="singlePageApp1" selectedPageName="homePage">
        <xe:appPage id="appPage1" pageName="homePage">
            <xe:djxmRoundRectList id="djxmRoundRectList1">
                <xp:label value="File Link:" id="FileLinkLabel"></xp:label>
                <xp:br></xp:br>

                <xp:link escape="true" text="Link" id="link1"
                    value="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">
                </xp:link>
            </xe:djxmRoundRectList>
            <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading1" label="Home">
            </xe:djxmHeading>
        </xe:appPage>
    </xe:singlePageApp>

</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out on an iPad with Domino v9.0.1 and on v8.5.3 (with ExtLib v853.20130315-0724 installed). In both cases the link opened in a new tab as expectedusing the code you posted.

Would you be able to upgrade to a newer version of the Extension Library, and try that?
http://extlib.openntf.org/?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library/releases/56832E9BD6A0615186257B4300349C59

The v853.20130315-0724 release was the final one released for 8.5.3, so I would try that.